# WCF Authorization via SharePoint Security Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, security, wcf, authorization

Would like to implement authentication and authorization operations on non-SharePoint hosted cross-domain WCF service via SharePoint 2010 Security Model, which is Windows Authentication.

So, a member of Contributors SharePoint group on site, will call WCF Service via Javascript AJAX REST. WCF Service will check authorization as below.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Contributor")]
public void Foo(string bar)
```

Members of the group will be able to make the call, but non-members will not.

What are the configuration required on WCF and how to sent SharePoint group membership of the current user by AJAX?

Able to configure WCF to request Windows Authentication - but not able to send current user SharePoint group membership from AJAX call.